# iterate entry.getkey() using for loop

Tags: java, iterator

I want to iterate the value of entry for getting keys and values of entry, but don't know, how to iterate entry. Please guide me.

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Vector<PromoteTable>>> hmIterate = linkedHashmp.entrySet().iterator();
        while(hmIterate.hasNext())
        {
            Entry<String, Vector<PromoteTable>> entry = hmIterate.next();
            Object[] result = new Object[noOfRecords];          
        }
```

Comment: `entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()`, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: @Bhaskar muuuuuuuuuuch easier! i agree. i just wanted to post that as an answer

Comment: Why do you insist on editing out the sample code? The question is more useful with it left in. For anyone else coming to this question, it's available in the edit history.

Comment: Hey Chris, thats my post and I have all right to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<PromoteTable>> entry : linkedHashmp.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Vector<PromoteTable> value = entry.getValue();
        Object[] result = new Object[noOfRecords];  
    }
```